# If the limit of a function at infinity is equal to L then the limit of the derivative of that function is 0.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:(0,+\infty)→\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function. If $f(x)\to L$ and $f'(x)\to M$, all when $x\to\infty$, show that $M=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, usually we ask that questions be included with what you have tried already and the context

Comment: The title does not agree with the question. The limit of the derivative of that function is $0$ ***if it exists***.

Comment: OK. I'm a newbie and I didn't know. Excuse me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for an answer without integrals:

Consider $f(x)$ and $f(x+1)$. By the Mean Value Theorem, for some $\zeta$ where
$x<\zeta<x+1,$ we have $f'(\zeta) = f(x+1) - f(x).$

Using this fact and the fact that $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to\infty,$
show there exists an unbounded sequence $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3,\ldots$
such that $f'(\zeta_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

But if $f'(x) \to M$ as $x \to\infty$ and $M > 0,$ then there is some $x_0$ and some $\delta > 0$ such that $f'(x) > \delta$ for all $x > x_0$.

Show that these last two paragraphs lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M>0$. Then for sufficiently large $x$ (say $x>R$), (using $\epsilon=M/2$ in the definition of a limit) $f’(x)\geq M/2$. Therefore $$f(x)=f(R)+\int_R^xf’(t)dt\geq f(R)+\int_R^x\frac M2=f(R)+\frac M2(x-R).$$ Therefore $f$ diverges as $x\to\infty$ and cannot be converging to a real number $L$.

The corresponding fact for $M<0$ can be obtained by replacing $f$ with $-f$. The only remaining possibility is that $M=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much but can you answer without using integral?